# Samsung U28R552UQR via HDMI + USB‑C Digital AV Multiport Adapter – bad quality

Tags: macos, display, hdmi

I have two Samsung U28R552UQR displays. One is connected via DisplayPort–to–USB-C, the other one via HDMI + [Apple's own USB‑C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/de/shop/product/MUF82ZM/A/usb%E2%80%91c-digital-av-multiport-adapter). The one connected via HDMI looks considerably worse.

This is the output of `ioreg -l -d0 -w 0 -r -c AppleDisplay`, in case it’s helpful:

```
+-o AppleDisplay  <class AppleDisplay, id 0x10000ca40, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 9>
    {
      "IOClass" = "AppleDisplay"
      "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
      "IOProviderClass" = "IODisplayConnect"
      "DisplayProductID" = 4119
      "IODisplayEDID" = <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>
      "IODisplayPrefsKeyOld" = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/EGP0@0/IOPP/EGP1@0/IOPP/GFX0@0/AMDRadeonX6000_AmdRadeonControllerNavi14/ATY,Boa@1/display0/AppleDisplay-4c2d-1017"
      "IODisplayPrefsKey" = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/EGP0@0/IOPP/EGP1@0/IOPP/GFX0@0-4c2d-1017-b38a4de4e70693f2"
      "IOProbeScore" = 2000
      "IOPowerManagement" = {"CapabilityFlags"=49152,"MaxPowerState"=3,"CurrentPowerState"=3}
      "IODisplayParameters" = {"pscn"={"min"=7500,"max"=10000,"value"=10000},"rgsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"bgsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"vblm"={"min"=0,"max"=196608,"value"=65536},"ownr"=4294969174,"ggsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536}}
      "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
      "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
      "IODisplayConnectFlags" = <00000000>
      "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
      "IODisplayAttributes" = {"IODisplayAttributes"=<676174760000000073676c6600000000726c6f63110100006364670080808000676c666401000000>,"IODisplayVSDBD85DC4"=<0178800b>,"IODisplayVSDB030C00"=<1000b84420002001>}
      "DisplayVendorID" = 19501
      "DisplaySerialNumber" = 809841742
    }
    

+-o AppleDisplay  <class AppleDisplay, id 0x10000ca44, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 9>
    {
      "IOClass" = "AppleDisplay"
      "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
      "IOProviderClass" = "IODisplayConnect"
      "DisplayProductID" = 4117
      "IODisplayEDID" = <00ffffffffffff004c2d15104e344530041f0104b53f24783ac8b5ad50449e250f5054bfef80714f810081c08180a9c0b300950001014dd000a0f0703e803020350078682100001a000000fd001e4b1e873c000a202020202020000000fc004c5532385235350a2020202020000000ff00484e4d523130303037380a2020013f02031cf0475f101f041303122309070783010000e305c000e3060501023a801871382d40582c450078682100001e565e00a0a0a029503020350078682100001a04740030f2705a80b0588a0078682100001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000085>
      "IODisplayPrefsKeyOld" = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/EGP0@0/IOPP/EGP1@0/IOPP/GFX0@0/AMDRadeonX6000_AmdRadeonControllerNavi14/ATY,Boa@2/display0/AppleDisplay-4c2d-1015"
      "IODisplayPrefsKey" = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/EGP0@0/IOPP/EGP1@0/IOPP/GFX0@0-4c2d-1015-94aedcc7a848d252"
      "IOProbeScore" = 2000
      "IOPowerManagement" = {"CapabilityFlags"=49152,"MaxPowerState"=3,"CurrentPowerState"=3}
      "IODisplayParameters" = {"pscn"={"min"=7500,"max"=10000,"value"=10000},"rgsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"bgsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"vblm"={"min"=0,"max"=196608,"value"=65536},"ownr"=4294969176,"ggsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536}}
      "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
      "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
      "IODisplayConnectFlags" = <00000000>
      "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
      "IODisplayAttributes" = {"IODisplayAttributes"=<676174760000000073676c6600000000726c6f63010000006364670080808000676c666401000000>}
      "DisplayVendorID" = 19501
      "DisplaySerialNumber" = 809841742
    }
```

The first one is the one that looks bad, the second one is the one that looks good. In particular, the first one seems to have an `80` as the 20th (counting from 0) EDID byte, which [indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) digital output with undefined bit depth and video interface. The second one seems to have a `b5`, which indicates digital output with 10-bit color depth and a DisplayPort interface, as expected. Is this a known issue with Apple’s adapter? Should I try overriding the EDID?

I am using a 16-inch Intel MacBook Pro from 2019.

Comment: If you switch connections (use HDMI+Adapter for the first, DP-USBC for the second), which one is worse?

Comment: Again the one that’s connected via HDMI.

Comment: If I use a DisplayPort–to–USB-C cable for the second monitor as well, then everything looks fine again, but I can’t spare the port.

Comment: That laptop has four USB-C ports.  And aren't you already consuming one port for the adapter?

Comment: I am in no way an expert on this subject. The OP refers to VESA, but for HDMI @ 3840x2160 the [user guide](https://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/202004/20200424093114575/BN46-01082A-Eng.pdf) for the monitor on page 45 refers to CEA. For DisplayPort @ 3840x2160, the user guide on page 44 refers to VESA.

Comment: IMO, what you are trying to accomplish probably is not possible with a cheap adaptor. If you want 4K @ 60 Hz DP, 96 W PD to the Mac and additional extras, then you would want something expensive such as [StarTech TB4CDOCK](https://www.startech.com/en-us/universal-laptop-docking-stations/tb4cdock).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Apple's adapter supports 4k@60 via HDMI, although how well it does it, I have no idea.  The CEA standards are what HDMI implements.

Comment: @bletted.medlar Is perhaps what you're trying to say with "can't spare the port", that you're trying to drive one of these two monitors by two different sources, and the other one is using the DP port on the monitor while the laptop uses HDMI?  If not, there is literally no reason to bother with the adapter, you're consuming the port on the laptop anyway, you should just use another cable.

Comment: @MarcWilson – One display is plugged directly into a USB-C port, and works well. The other display (along with the charger and a USB-A Yubikey; 65W of charging is sufficient for me) is plugged via HDMI–Apple dongle–USB-C.

Comment: My thought was to avoid HDMI altogether. If USB 2.0 is fast enough and 87 W PD to the Mac is good enough, then you could try something cheaper such as [this hub](https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-Adapter-Charging-MacBook-Laptops/dp/B0CFM6Q9HK/ref=sr_1_1?dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.7Hz604gZGIG1Fc2634uubI5e426E-upNNVU_-e7-bW0.Zxx-f_MJS0fMqO77VnthUJpeQonIiKusdoYAo8m0X0Y&dib_tag=se&m=A3ONY0LQREXQHD&qid=1711414777&refinements=p_6%3AA3ONY0LQREXQHD&s=electronics&sr=1-1&srs=20699470011&th=1).

Comment: In the past, I have purchased the same Apple adaptor you have. The tried connecting the adaptor between a 2018 Mac mini and several different 1080 HDMI displays. The image quality was not very good. I ended up returning the adaptor. Your problem may just be with the adaptor itself and not HDMI.

Comment: Seconded re getting off HDMI.  HDMI should always be avoided.